# Safari 13 Automatic Navigation in Iframe

Tags: cookies, iframe, safari, azure-active-directory

We have two Applications

- Container
- Child

Child opens inside Container using iframe control and both applications use Microsoft Azure AD for authentication. When Child opens in Container iframe it will first redirects to Microsoft Azure login page automatically for authentication. This automatic redirection cause iframe to stop further navigation bcz this will considered as security breach by Apple. [Safari 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes)

> Changed the behavior for third party iframes to prevent them automatically navigating the page.

Before Safari 13 this solution is working fine by just enabling 3rd party cookies setting.

Please suggest any solution to bypass this security feature.